# getting string like when I return a list

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, controller, asp.net-core-3.1

The result I am getting

> falsef005fdc9-7781-4c75-9f54-0a05a7fc6e71bc3d0990-2f44-491f-a25a-3771772d6a61false2017-10-10T08:43:16.0831010019false

I am getting like the format as below when I use the postman.

1. Question: How do I remove `[]`? I tried to remove `ToList()` but it didn't work.
2. Question: Why I am getting a string like result instead of json?

[image]

**controller method**

```
public IEnumerable<ClientModel> GetClients()
{
    var clients = ClientHelper.GetAllClients();
    var result = (from c in clients
                  select c).ToList(); 

    return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ClientModel>>(result);

}
```

Comment: **Q1**: Your method is returning `IEnumerable` which means basically an array. So that `[]` represents array in JSON. Do you want to return single `ClientModel` or something? **Q2:** this is exactly JSON which format is text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this namespace

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

and

```
var json_result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result );
```

You must get json data in json_result